# A bubble notification tool for Windows that doesn't require running a daemon like Growl or Snarl?

Tags: windows, user-interface

Something like CocoaDialog's [Bubble Control](http://cocoadialog.sourceforge.net/documentation.html#bubble_control) is exactly what I'm looking for.
Unfortunately, the cross-platform port (wxCocoaDialog) doesn't implement that bubble feature.

[ToasterBox](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/ToasterBox.html) looks suitable, but I'd prefer a more compact solution which doesn't require keeping Python and WxPython around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an Autohotkey script called [Notify()](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic48668.html), which turned out to perfectly fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

How about **Snarl**?

http://www.fullphat.net/index.php

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped Snarl as 'Snarf'.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use .Net? Investigate the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) control.

Comment: NotifyIcon has balloon notifications, but not toasters does it?